# Android app cannot connect to server on mobile data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Android app which uses Sockets (and ssl) connection to a server. This works fine on wifi, but on mobile data it doesn't. This is code for connection:

```
// Load the server keystore
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
keyStore.load(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sys), certificatePassword.toCharArray());

// Create a custom trust manager that accepts the server self-signed certificate
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

// Create the SSLContext for the SSLSocket to use
SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslctx.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

// Create SSLSocketFactory
SSLSocketFactory factory = sslctx.getSocketFactory();

// Create socket using SSLSocketFactory
client = factory.createSocket(ipAddress, port); <-- Here application hangs
```

As I described in the line above, the app hangs in this line and I get an exception: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect ... ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

My app manifest is defined like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

...
activities, etc.
```

Every other app on my phone works correctly on a mobile data. Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your apps server locally(i.e on your machine and not on a cloud server etc), then your app will only run on wifi provided your PC and mobile are connected to the same wifi.

If you switch to a cloud server and provide the appropriate IP address of your server while connecting then you wouldn't face the above issue